# FactoryBot factory with static attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I want to create an integration test for XML serialization, that retrieves data from database and later create the XML files.
I need to have some factories with static attributes, ie, they always have the same values, to allow to set the expectations on the generated XML.

So for example in my `User` factory I have:

```
  factory :static_user, class: User do
    id { '78474912-7728-4478-8810-151a1347d546' }
    role { :admin }
    email { 'john.root@mail.com' }
    password { 'password' }
    password_confirmation { 'password' }
    created_at { Time.parse 'Wed, 26 Sep 2018 11:06:59 UTC +00:00' }
    updated_at { Time.parse 'Wed, 26 Sep 2018 11:06:59 UTC +00:00' }
  end
```

Although when I try to use it as association in another factory I need to wrap it with a custom initialization:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :static_order, class: Order do
    association :user, factory: :static_user do
      initialize_with { User.find_or_initialize_by(build(:static_user)) }
    end
  end
end
```

How can I avoid this?

I could use `DatabaseCleaner` gem to have the database empty prior every test, but I will get and error of duplicated attributes (that have a unique validation) if I try to create a list of items.

Comment: Using fixed values really just means you are using your factories as fixtures. Instead of writing `expect(foo.bar).to eq 'baz'` you can instead you do `expect(foo.bar).to eq factory_instance.bar` which means that you no longer have a tight coupling between the spec and a factory which is a good thing.

Comment: If the id is static, why not set user_id instead of user? Use the same fixed string as your static user id

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that creating a new `User` for each `create(:static_order)` is the desired behaviour.

Setting the `id` in the factory will break when creating several users. You could use a sequence instead, or set the id yourself when instantiating users, so that you still control the id. If you want your orders to share the same user, you need to pass them explicitly.

```rb
let(:user) { create(:user, id: '78474912-7728-4478-8810-151a1347d546') }
let!(:order1) { create(:static_order, user: user) }
let!(:order2) { create(:static_order, user: user) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @max references, I end up going with fixtures which make sense since they can be run in transaction and provide static values.

So I'm posting this, as if someone tries to follow the same have an advise that is going on wrong direction, because this is what's fixtures are for.